# What policies to configure an app for deployment with AWS Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am following [a tutorial on how to deploy web applications with AWS](https://youtu.be/ir5qqByo04g?t=4744). I'm configuring the policies for a group of users but I can't find them. Indeed it looks like I have to configure the ElasticBeanstalkService and the ElasticBeanstalkService.

[image]

But I don't have them here:

[image]

I tried without choosing any policy but it returns:

```
Enter Application Name
(default is "mlh-localhost-build-and-deploy-aws-starter"):
ERROR: NotAuthorizedError - Operation Denied. User: arn:aws:iam::193798676932:user/lhd-build-aws is not authorized to perform: elasticbeanstalk:CreateAppli
cation on resource: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:eu-west-3:193798676932:application/mlh-localhost-build-and-deploy-aws-starter
```

## Update

I finally decided to give administrator rights on Elastic Beanstalk, `AdministratorAccess-AWSElasticBeanstalk` to this user:

```
It appears you are using Python. Is this correct?
(Y/n): Y
Select a platform branch.
1) Python 3.8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2
2) Python 3.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2
3) Python 3.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux
(default is 1): 1  # <-- Actually I am using Python 3.9

Do you wish to continue with CodeCommit? (Y/n): Y
EB CLI does not have the right permissions to access CodeCommit. List of IAM policies needed by EB CLI, please configure and try again.
 codecommit:CreateRepository
 codecommit:CreateBranch
 codecommit:GetRepository
 codecommit:ListRepositories
 codecommit:ListBranches
To learn more, see Docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/access-permissions.html
ERROR: ServiceError - User: arn:aws:iam::193798676932:user/lhd-build-aws is not authorized to perform: codecommit:ListRepositories
```

Then I added `AWSCodeCommitFullAccess` but now I have another problem, but it has no name:

```
Type a keypair name.
(Default is aws-eb):
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in C:\Users\antoi\.ssh\aws-eb.
Your public key has been saved in C:\Users\antoi\.ssh\aws-eb.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:MdnOmGEkiWUp116mywcRqnVIEZsgGBQmjR8VjFCVCdk aws-eb
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 2048]----+
 Hay cosas aqui
|                 |
|                 |
+----[SHA256]-----+
ERROR: NotAuthorizedError - Operation Denied. You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message: Efw29Zjkv8doX4V9CHXv
2RibQWKRZ-p5bXK6F-2ktZNb0gydzTdX_CkQ7nYqzf5PDA-UvZZsz9k8V9d-aVvTKaroR6BvfGQ1nxcCrRTmIoUMo_KOlNmd-7eotWe07QGA2-G8dJavD1ZwutQMXH_5T1U_pEZvmTWEyFewwr9C1C5QRgd
J5JnXMJ0K2ndC00FoJlUt2quFaCy-8lUMFRqoCmn0aIWqNWGFmUKiMqFUtOxTPPIic8ANzEknEI82ROeGmA701CXkHOwyv5CpM84h06YEmWH9pi8B5uXyjVSd2fDgYzxKpKrex5J--7FMX6Kj75W7JIN2mD
83wxG24kRLnxbLr-zfEs4InySjfpORLDWoC8BpR4cO2JpScVZ86P1PIWIPLnlxok7lOF4I15muQu78jY1iu31RVgUpcJAyu0phevyOA7oZ5viPe1MRTYTiVgHDbsuiUGCP8bIrIlGN1AoXxtjlwqsxXbgGr
XjRlciIfHCcH5-DNxOpk_6MaGpXEt8Vf98AT0HrsBwRfPB-Kg
```

Aquí debería haber estado más bien conectado con el servidor como en el tutorial:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: I'm not sure, what is the problem?

Comment: Thanks for passing by, @Marcin ! I updated the question a bit. The problem is that despite bypassing access policy issues by setting very wide rights (I didn't find `AWSElasticBeanstalkManagedUpdatesCustomerRolePolicy`), in the end I'm not reaching the server to further on my app deployment level like they do in the tutorial(which you can see in the screenshot)